# How do I add values sampled from a list to two nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

In this code block, I am trying to sample two values from a list and add them to a specific key/value pair in each of two nested dictionaries that share the same key/value structure. I have commented to clarify my intentions.

## Here is the list of values to random sample from

```
gym_list = ['reddit.com','amazon.com','twitter.com','linkedin.com','ebay.com','netflix.com','stackoverflow.com','github.com','quora.com','google.com']
```

## This is my attempt to create range of two key/values pairs in adjacent nested dictionaries

```
for i in range(poke_players[['player_1']['gyms_visited']],poke_players[['player_2']['gyms_visited']]):
if poke_players[['player_1']['gyms_visited']] : None;    #If first key/value pair has no value
poke_players[['player_1']['gyms_visited']].append([sample(gym_list,2)]); #add random sample to first key/value pair
   else:
        poke_players[['player_2']['gyms_visited']] : None;    #If second key/value pair has no value
        poke_players[['player_1']['gyms_visited']].append([sample(gym_list,2)]):    #add random sample to second key/value pair
    return poke_players    #return the updated dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue seems to be that you're not writing valid Python syntax.

I can see a couple of ways to go about the problem you describe.  Let's first approach this as nested dictionaries, making one a `defaultdict` collection.  This is *not* an exact implementation of your code but an approximation that shows how to create and manipulate the data structure:

```
from random import sample
from collections import defaultdict

gym_list = ['reddit.com', 'amazon.com', 'twitter.com', 'linkedin.com', 'ebay.com', 'netflix.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'github.com', 'quora.com', 'google.com']

poke_players = defaultdict(dict)

def initialize_poke_players():

    if 'gyms_visited' not in poke_players['player_1']:  # If first key/value pair has no value
        poke_players['player_1']['gyms_visited'] = sample(gym_list, 2)  # add random sample to first key/value pair

    if 'gyms_visited' not in poke_players['player_2']:  # If second key/value pair has no value
        poke_players['player_2']['gyms_visited'] = sample(gym_list, 2)  # add random sample to second key/value pair

initialize_poke_players()

print("Player 1:", poke_players['player_1']['gyms_visited'])
print("Player 2:", poke_players['player_2']['gyms_visited'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
Player 1: ['twitter.com', 'google.com']
Player 2: ['reddit.com', 'linkedin.com']
>
```

A simpler, single dictionary, approach is *compound keys* consisting of tuples of strings:

```
from random import sample

gym_list = ['reddit.com', 'amazon.com', 'twitter.com', 'linkedin.com', 'ebay.com', 'netflix.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'github.com', 'quora.com', 'google.com']

poke_players = {}

def initialize_poke_players():

    if ('player_1', 'gyms_visited') not in poke_players:  # If first key/value pair has no value
        poke_players[('player_1', 'gyms_visited')] = sample(gym_list, 2)  # add random sample to first key/value pair

    if ('player_2', 'gyms_visited') not in poke_players:  # If second key/value pair has no value
        poke_players[('player_2', 'gyms_visited')] = sample(gym_list, 2)  # add random sample to second key/value pair

initialize_poke_players()

print("Player 1:", poke_players[('player_1', 'gyms_visited')])
print("Player 2:", poke_players[('player_2', 'gyms_visited')])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean, concise code in your reply. I see what you mean about the bad syntax in my initial post. I can see how to improve that now.